# C++ Printing Vector Adding New Line

Tags: c++, vector, ostream

I have a vector of structs.

```
struct myStruct{
string text;
int num;
};

vector<myStruct> foo;
```

And I am attempting to print the text followed by a space, then the number. Like so:

> foobar 5

But when trying to print my vector using

```
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open ("file.txt");

for(int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++) {
        outputFile << foo[x].text << " " << foo[x].num << endl;
    }
```

It prints like

```
foobar  
 5 
moretext  
 8
```

With an extra newline and space. I can't figure out how to get rid of it and print it on the same line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked if `foo[x].text` has a newline character at its end?

Comment: @Mark Garcia I am using getline(input, foo.text). So it should discard the newline character, no?

Comment: It also seems to be working fine with cout, just not with my output file...

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether foo[x].text includes \r or \n.

Comment: It does not. I have checked this.

Answer (score 0):

*"I am using getline(input, foo.text). So it should discard the newline character"*

`std::getline()` adds a carriage return at end ,  if your `input` stream has windows-style line-breaks (CRLF), and you're using a program on unix, which has LF

You need to trim it, using some like :

`foo.text.erase(foo.text.find_last_not_of("\n\r")+1);`

Comment: Still no luck using this code. It works just fine using cout, but breaks using the output file

Answer (score 0):

One hack would be merging the string before you pass it to outputFile.

or

Have you tried playing around with the mode setting with open() method?
e.g.

> outputFile.open ("file.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);

Comment: I would try this. Also there is no need to use 'endl' unless you want to flush the file after every line. Just use '\n' otherwise.